# P/Invoke: Memory corruption with pointer

Tags: c++, mono, pinvoke

I'm wrapping part of the FBX SDK (closed, with a public API) with Mono (so COM, CLI aren't options) and a bunch of extern's, and it was all going well until I had to return a non-pointer instance. [See here](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/index.html?url=cpp_ref/class_fbx_object.html,topicNumber=cpp_ref_class_fbx_object_html186c6ed2-d433-4e25-9d74-e726541bcf98,hash=a29de8e90544c8c17c85c5b260c1ef93a)

The crucial point is that I have to return it back to C++ for another call. Because I don't know how you'd do that without a pointer, I returned it as such:

```
FBXAPI FbxProperty* Object_GetFirstProperty(FbxObject* obj)
{
    return &obj->GetFirstProperty();
}
```

..and it's not until I try something like the next snippet that I get the *"System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."* message.

```
FBXAPI const wchar_t* Property_GetName(FbxProperty* prop)
{
    int c = prop->GetSrcPropertyCount();
    return L"Test";
}
```

If I use almost identical code using the same calls in C++, it's fine. I've done another ~20 function calls in the same manner but without having to "pointerfy" it, and they're all fine too, so I don't think my DllImport's are to blame. So if the reference is to be blame, how else do I do it? Surely I don't store a global static reference somewhere just because someone called it from the API?

Any help is appreciated, C/C++ and the explicit way it handles memory is new to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: I find your question confusing: The title indicates that the question is about a non-pointer return value and you then proceed to explain how you need to return a pointer. Also, the question is about P/Invoke but you only provide the C++ signatures, not the corresponding C# P/Invoke signatures.

Comment: We've no idea what FbxProperty is. And we cannot tell whether or not the address you return remains valid. And you didn't show any c#.

Comment: Is C++/CLI an option for you? If so, this is predestined for writing a C# wrapper on Windows; saves you all the trouble with proper P/Invoke.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've clarified with new question title and clarified that this is intended for cross-platform (mono) distribution so CLI isn't an option - I wish it were!

Comment: Since we don't know what this type is, nor what your C# code is, we cannot help in detail. Why won't you show this detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your program is crashing because the property you were getting the pointer to does no longer exist. Let me clarify and start by dissecting the following:

```
FBXAPI FbxProperty* Object_GetFirstProperty(FbxObject* obj)
{
    return &obj->GetFirstProperty();
}
```

I looked up the documentation of FBX, and `FbxObject::GetFirstProperty()` has a return type of `FbxProperty`. Notice that the return value isn't any pointer or reference? That means you get a so called 'auto-variable', or in this case a 'temporary'. This kind of object only lasts until you leave the scope, which in this case is your `Object_GetFirstProperty()` of your wrapper. After that, the object is cleaned up and removed from the memory stack. `FbxObject::GetFirstProperty()` gives you a copy of the property, not an actual reference. Internally it might be different, but your wrapper is concerned about the property object itself, not it's content.

So what you are doing is you get a pointer to an address that is no longer valid later on when you pass it to your `Property_GetName()`.

C++ behaves differently than C# in regards to object lifetime. An object in C# called `MyObj` can be thought of as a C++ pointer type like `MyObject*` - it's a like a reference value. In C# you have also value-types like `struct` and so forth, which are the equivalent to the C++ auto-variable. All auto-variables are destroyed when their lifetime scope is left.

What you'd have to do to overcome your problem is to save the object you get from `FbxObject::GetFirstProperty()` directly, and not a pointer to it. You'd basically have to marshall the object into a proper .NET class so that it's contents are not lost.

Alternatively, you could just allocate dynamic memory and copy the object you get from `FbxObject::GetFirstPoperty()` there, and return a pointer to your own memory. Of course you'd have to delete this memory later on manually. Here is a simple example:

```
FBXAPI FbxProperty* Object_GetFirstProperty(FbxObject* obj)
{
    // Allocate custom memory.
    char* myMem = new char[sizeof(FbxProperty)];

    // Copy the property's content there.
    std::memcpy(myMem, &obj->GetFirstProperty(), sizeof(FbxProperty));

    // Return custom memory address.
    return reinterpret_cast<FbxProperty*>(myMem);
}
```

This should solve your memory corruption issue. But in C++ you'd have to free this memory manually when your are finished with the property by doing ths:

```
FBXAPI void Property_Free(FbxProperty* prop)
{
    // Free previously allocated memory
    delete[] prop;
}
```

But this attempt may cause other problems, depending on how the actual `FbxProperty` handles it's data inside. You are creating a copy of the object, sure, but if the original temporaty/auto-variable deletes important memory upon destruction, you would have similar issus to the ones you have now.

If you are REALLY witty you could just write real wrapper classes for every FBX type you require and marshall the whole class type instead of generating separete C functions you have to P/Invoke every time you want to get a value or a property.